# Spring integration DSL Scatter-Gather async/parallel execution for multiple recipientFlows

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

we are trying to make parallel calls to different recipient using scatter-gather and it works fine. But the second recipient flow is not starting unless the first one is complete(traced in Zipkin). is there is a way to make all recipients async.. very similar to split-aggregate with executor channel.

```
public IntegrationFlow flow1() {

        return flow -> flow
                .split().channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .scatterGather(
                        scatterer -> scatterer
                                .applySequence(true)
                                .recipientFlow(flow2())
                                .recipientFlow(flow3())
                                .recipientFlow(flow4())
                                .recipientFlow(flow5()),
                        gatherer -> gatherer
                                .outputProcessor(messageGroup -> {
                                    Object request = gatherResponse(messageGroup);
                                    return createResponse(request);
                                }))
                .aggregate();
    }
```

flow2(),flow3(),flow4() methods are methods with `InterationFlow` as return type.

sample code `flow2()` :

```
public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
        return integrationFlowDefinition -> integrationFlowDefinition
                .enrichHeaders(
                        h -> h.header(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE))
                .transform(ele -> createRequest1(ele))                  
                .wireTap("asyncXMLLogging")
                .handle(wsGateway.applyAsHandler(endpoint1))
                .transform(
                        ele -> response2(ele));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible with the mentioned `executor channel`. All you recipient flows must really start from the `ExecutorChannel`. In your case you have to modify all of them to something like this:

```
public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor(taskExexecutor()))
            .enrichHeaders(
                    h -> h.header(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE))
            .transform(ele -> createRequest1(ele))                  
            .wireTap("asyncXMLLogging")
            .handle(wsGateway.applyAsHandler(endpoint1))
            .transform(
                    ele -> response2(ele))
            .get();
}
```

Pay attention to the `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor(taskExexecutor()))`. That's exactly how you can make each sub-flow async.

**UPDATE**

For the older Spring Integration version without `IntegrationFlow` improvement for the sub-flows we can do like this:

```
public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition -> integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .enrichHeaders(
                    h -> h.header(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE))
            .transform(ele -> createRequest1(ele))                  
            .wireTap("asyncXMLLogging")
            .handle(wsGateway.applyAsHandler(endpoint1))
            .transform(
                    ele -> response2(ele));
}
```

This is similar to what you show in the comment above.

Comment: while i test `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))` .  this poses another problem where `from` has a channel name; some thing like IntegrationFlows.from("enricherChannel")

Comment: my bad : IntegrationFlows.from("enricherChannel") .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())) . this should work just fine. it gets the message in to the flow and aync rest of the flow. got it!!!

Comment: Well, you don't need that extra channel. This one is fully enough for you: `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageChannels.executor("enricherChannel", Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))`

Comment: Getting exception on flow2() after adding `executor & from` combination  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null.


Traced to :
 `@Override
 public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flow) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
 }`

Comment: This is interesting , i modified `. recipientFlow` to `recipient` and named the channel , the application starts fine; But the `. recipientFlow` still throws unsupported exception

Comment: Well, it looks like you don't use the latest Spring Integration. So, yes: in this case would be better to go the classical `recipient` based on the channel name from the sub-flow beans. Of you can do like I show in the UPDATE of my answer.

Comment: What does the implementation of `taskExexecutor()` have to look like for this to work ?

Comment: I found I could replace `taskExexecutor()` with an injected instance of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`.